# Form input to define number of variables in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I had a class assignment to create a form letter that allows form input to insert the entered data into the document once a submit button is pressed.

The newest assignment instructs me to add a new input field to allow me to input the number of recipients to create this letter for, such that I input a number and hit enter, and the document updates to have multiple input fields for each recipient in a JS array.  Then, I can type in a new receipient name in each field created, and have a new page create the mockups of the letter to each recipient recursively.

In other words, the web page says "How many people do you want to send this to?" - I put in a number, hit enter, and the page updates for a "Name" field for each person, plus the other fields.  Then, after all fields are filled and submit is pressed, a new page opens and shows the full form letter for each name I input.

I dont have a clue how to do this, and I bumbled through the initial assignment.  Any suggestions?  And yes, I'm a 100% JS noob, and I'm not all that well versed with HTML5 either, so please be verbose and gentle with me. :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint: Use a `for` loop, and in the loop you use `document.createElement()` to create new elements, and `form.appendChild()` to add them to the form.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Surely the lessons that were taught in the class before the assignment mentioned these things.

Comment: Greetings!  I recommend new or returning users review [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  I would also suggest that, given that this is a class assignment, you review [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Barmar, you'd think  - however, this class is part of Capella's FlexPath, and there IS no instruction or class.  I will take your advice and start learning the for loop and createElement commands right now.  Thank you!!!